# OSX Mail - Gmail account sync issues

Tags: macos, gmail

I had my mail in sync with the MacOSX Mail application about two months, however since last week i have experienced issues with the account synchronization (after a while of trying to sync it ask for a password).

I have done some google but there are not answers, anyone can tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Mac Mail opens a lot of IMAP connections per client.  If you have a lot of Mac Mail clients open on a local network, it's possible that for your whole internal network, you are going over a server-defined limit for your IP.

As far as I know there is no way to configure how many IMAP connections Mac Mail creates.  One thing you can do is to close (right-click, exit) other Mac Mail clients on the network and see if your client can then connect.

For smaller email providers you might ask them to raise the IMAP connection limit.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2547839?start=0&tstart=0

http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=97150

Comment: How does this answer the OPs question? He's asking about account sync'ing and you're talking about the number of IMAP connections. Just curious.

Comment: I'm guessing it's the same problem we had when adding more and more accounts on our LAN.  The fact that it was working and then suddenly stopped working and asked for a password is a giveaway.

I'm not saying that it's definitely not some other part of the sync process (if the OP is indeed trying to sync, not check for new mail) but it's one of the more common problems with Mac Mail.

Comment: i have only one mac on my network.